# In Rust, how can I make this code less repetitive?

Tags: rust, ownership, borrow-checker

The goal is to write a function that gets two paths, `input_dir` and `output_dir`, and convertes all markdown files from `input_dir` to html files in `output_dir`.

I finally managed to get it to run but it was rather frustrating. The parts that should be hard are super easy: the actual conversion from Markdown to HTML is effectively only one line. The seemingly easy parts are what took me the longest. Using a vector of paths and put all files into it is something I replaced with the `glob` crate. Not because I couldn't get it to work but it was a mess of `if let` and `unwrap`. A simple function that iterates over the list of elements and figures out which of them are actually files and not directories? Either I need four indentation levels if `if let` or I freak out over `match`es.

What am I doing wrong?

But lets start with some things I tried to get a list of items in a directory filtered to only contain actual files:

```
use std::fs;
use std::vec::Vec;


fn list_files (path: &str) -> Result<Vec<&str>, &str> {
    if let Ok(dir_list) = fs::read_dir(path) {
        Ok(dir_list.filter_map(|e| {
            match e {
                Ok(entry) => match entry.file_type() {
                    Ok(_) => entry.file_name().to_str(),
                    _ => None
                },
                _ => None
            }
        }).collect())
    } else {
        Err("nope")
    }
}


fn main() {
    let files = list_files("testdir");
    println!("{:?}", files.unwrap_or(Vec::new()));
}
```

So, this code doesn't build, because the file name in Line 10 doesn't live long enough. I guess I could somehow create an owned `String` but that would introduce another nesting level because `OsStr.to_string()` returns a `Result`.

Now I looked through the code of the `glob` crate and they just use a mutable vector:

```
fn list_files (path: &str) -> Result<Vec<&str>, &str> {
    let mut list = Vec::new();

    if let Ok(dir_list) = fs::read_dir(path) {
        for entry in dir_list {
            if let Ok(entry) = entry {
                if let Ok(file_type) = entry.file_type() {
                    if file_type.is_file() {
                        if let Some(name) = entry.file_name().to_str() {
                            list.push(name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Ok(list)
    } else {
        Err("nope")
    }
}
```

This not only adds crazy nesting, it also fails with the same problem. If I change from `Vec<&str>` to `Vec<String>`, it works:

```
fn list_files (path: &str) -> Result<Vec<String>, &str> {
    let mut list = Vec::new();

    if let Ok(dir_list) = fs::read_dir(path) {
        for entry in dir_list {
            if let Ok(entry) = entry {
                if let Ok(file_type) = entry.file_type() {
                    if file_type.is_file() {
                        if let Ok(name) = entry.file_name().into_string() {
                            list.push(name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Ok(list)
    } else {
        Err("nope")
    }
}
```

Looks like I should apply that to my first try, right?

```
fn list_files (path: &str) -> Result<Vec<String>, &str> {
    if let Ok(dir_list) = fs::read_dir(path) {
        Ok(dir_list.filter_map(|e| {
            match e {
                Ok(entry) => match entry.file_type() {
                    Ok(_) => Some(entry.file_name().into_string().ok()),
                    _ => None
                },
                _ => None
            }
        }).collect())
    } else {
        Err("nope")
    }
}
```

At least a bit shorter… but it fails to compile because **a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `std::option::Option<std::string::String>`**.

It is hard to stay patient here. Why does `.filter_map` return `Option`s instead of just using them to filter? Now I have to change line 15 from `}).collect())` to `}).map(|e| e.unwrap()).collect())` which iterates once more over the result set.

That can't be right!

Comment: `ok()` returns `Option` and then you wrap it into `Some`. You end up with `Option<Option<...>>`. Remove `Some(...)` from `Some(entry.file_name().into_string().ok())`. It is not a complete answer, but at least it will allow you to get going.

Comment: If your code works (I find it hard to tell from reading your question), then asking for a way to write it better is [better suited for Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/32521).

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster, but my question was not so much about the piece of code, I only wrote that as an example. Instead I wanted to see what my general problem is that causes this code to be so crazy nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can massively rely on [`?` operator](https://m4rw3r.github.io/rust-questionmark-operator):

```
use std::fs;
use std::io::{Error, ErrorKind};

fn list_files(path: &str) -> Result<Vec<String>, Error> {
    let mut list = Vec::new();

    for entry in fs::read_dir(path)? {
        let entry = entry?;
        if entry.file_type()?.is_file() {
            list.push(entry.file_name().into_string().map_err(|_| {
                Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidData, "Cannot convert file name")
            })?)
        }
    }

    Ok(list)
}
```

Do not forget that you can split your code into functions or implement your own `trait`s to simplify the final code:

```
use std::fs;
use std::io::{Error, ErrorKind};

trait CustomGetFileName {
    fn get_file_name(self) -> Result<String, Error>;
}

impl CustomGetFileName for std::fs::DirEntry {
    fn get_file_name(self) -> Result<String, Error> {
        Ok(self.file_name().into_string().map_err(|_|
            Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidData, "Cannot convert file name")
        )?)
    }
}

fn list_files(path: &str) -> Result<Vec<String>, Error> {
    let mut list = Vec::new();

    for entry in fs::read_dir(path)? {
        let entry = entry?;
        if entry.file_type()?.is_file() {
            list.push(entry.get_file_name()?)
        }
    }

    Ok(list)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Boiethios ! I saw that operator earlier but everytime I wanted to use it, it didn't work for me.

Comment: Maybe because it was in nightly version only, before.

Comment: @koehr Updated!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer with iterators, [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f2d8af11b5ead1fb362b161354dd238d&version=stable)

```
use std::fs;
use std::error::Error;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn list_files(path: &str) -> Result<Vec<PathBuf>, Box<Error>> {
    let x = fs::read_dir(path)?
        .filter_map(|e| e.ok())
        .filter(|e| e.metadata().is_ok())
        .filter(|e| e.metadata().unwrap().is_file())
        .map(|e| e.path())
        .collect();

    Ok(x)
}

fn main() {
    let path = ".";
    for res in list_files(path).unwrap() {
        println!("{:#?}", res);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How good is the Rust compiler in optimizing such things? Because I wouldn't like to iterate over and over again.

Comment: that's the beautiful thing about iterators, this is only one iteration as there is only one call to collect

Comment: This answer is great! However, there is a difference with the OP's code because in your code, you do not return at first error. You only silently discard them.